# Delete manually added table row by Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to make an edit form for a previously created form and I want to add/remove rows from this table.

The issue is I can't delete the manually added row. I searched a lot and finally understand that event delegation should be implemented but couldn't figure out how and where to do that. Surely delete button works after page reload, but of course page reload is not wanted.

Any help appriciated.

HTML Button gets default ids from database on page load via PHP. ie remove_42 where 42 is retrieved from db.

Add function:

- Clones the last row and delete content,
- Creates a new row in database and gets the id of last created row via Ajax
- Assigns this id to new button id.

```
    $('#add').click(function() {
        var ele = $('.itemslists tbody tr:last');
        var ele_clone = ele.clone();
        ele_clone.find('input, select').prop("disabled", false).val('');
        ele_clone.find('td div.dummy').removeClass('has-error has-success');
        ele_clone.find('td div.input-icon i').removeClass('fa-check fa-warning');
        ele_clone.find('input').val('0');
        ele_clone.find('td:last').show();
        ele.after(ele_clone);
            
        $('.remove').show();
            
        var hash1g = '<?php echo $podata_hash; ?>';
        var hash2g = '<?php echo $podata_hash2; ?>';
            
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'cbdelrow.php',
            cache: false,
            data: {action: 'add_row', hash1: hash1g, hash2: hash2g },
    
            success: function(response) {
                 ele_clone.find('.remove').val(response);
                 var newId = "remove_" + response;
                 ele_clone.find('td button').attr("id", newId);
            }
        });
    });
```

Remove Function:

- Splits the id to get row id,
- Deletes the related row in database via Ajax with row id
- Recalculate amounts etc

```
$(document).on("click", ".remove", function() {
        
    rows = $('table#tbl_edit tr:last').index() + 1;
    if (rows == 2) {
        processForm();
        $('.remove').hide();
        
        $(this).parent().remove();
        update_amounts();
        
    } else if (rows == 1) {
        $('.remove').hide();
            
    } else {
        processForm();
        update_amounts();
        $(this).parent().remove();
                        
    }
}); 
function processForm() { 
    var btn_id = this.id;
    var row_id = btn_id.split('_')[1];
    $.ajax( {
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'cbdelrow.php',
        data: { btn_val: row_id },
        success: function(response) {
            // Silme islemi basariliysa gerekli islemler yapilir.
            $("button[value='"+row_id+"']").closest('tr').remove();
            update_amounts();   
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert('Error while delete.');
        }
    } );
}

// Bind click event to remove buttons
$('.remove').click(processForm);
```

EDIT: HTML Part Added

```
    <table class="table table-bordered" style="width: auto; min-width:880px; vertical-align:middle;">
        <tr class="head headtop">
            <td width="100px"><?php echo $language['quantity']; ?></td>
            <td width="520px"><?php echo $language['product-desc']; ?></td>
            <td width="180px"><?php echo $language['cost-center']; ?></td>
            <td width="80px"><?php echo $language['fixture']; ?></td>
            <td width="130px"><?php echo $language['unit-price']; ?></td>
            <td width="80px" style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $language['tax']; ?></td>
            <td width="130px"><?php echo $language['total-price']; ?></td>
            <td width="30px" style="background-color:#fff;"><div align="right"><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="buttonaddline btn-success btn-xs">+</button></div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="table table-bordered itemslists" style="width: auto; min-width:880px;" id="tbl_edit">
        <tbody>
            <?php
                while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td width="100px"><input type="text" name="item_qty[]" id="item_qty" class="item_qty form-control aaa" value="<?php echo $row['item_qty']; ?>" /></td>
                <td width="520px"><input type="text" name="item_name[]" id="item_name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['item_name']; ?>" /></td>
                <td width="180px">
                    <select name="item_dvsn[]" class="form-control">
                    <?php
                        foreach ($costcenters as $costcenter) {
                            $selectedcc = ($costcenter == $row['item_dvsn']) ? "selected" : "";
                            echo "<option value='$costcenter' $selectedcc>$costcenter</option>";
                        }
                    ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td width="80px">
                    <select name="item_fixture[]" class="form-control">
                        <option class="limit" value="<?php echo $language['opt-yes']; ?>" <?php $selects = "selected"; if ($row['item_fixture'] == $language['opt-yes']) { echo $selects; } else { } ?>><?php echo $language['opt-yes']; ?></option>
                        <option class="limit" value="<?php echo $language['opt-no']; ?>" <?php $selects = "selected"; if ($row['item_fixture'] == $language['opt-no']) { echo $selects; } else { } ?>><?php echo $language['opt-no']; ?></option>
                                            
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td width="130px"><input type="text" name="item_unitp[]" id="item_unitp" class="item_unitp form-control sss" style="text-align:right;" value="<?php echo $row['item_unitp']; ?>" /></td>
                <td width="80px"><input type="text" name="item_tax[]" id="item_tax" class="item_tax form-control ddd" style="text-align:center;" value="<?php echo $row['item_tax']; ?>" /></td>
                <td width="130px"><input type="text" name="item_totalp[]" id="item_totalp" class="item_totalp form-control fff" style="text-align:right;" value="<?php echo $row['item_totalp']; ?>" /></td>
                                            
                <td class="hide"><input type="text" name="item_id[]" class="borderless editbg left" style="display:none;" value="<?php echo $row['item_id']; ?>" /></td>
                <td><button type="button" id="remove_<?php echo $row['item_id']; ?>" name="remove" data-row="" value="<?php echo $row['item_id']; ?>" class="remove buttonremoveline btn-danger btn-xs">-</button></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

EDIT 2: Rendered HTML added

```
    <table class="table table-bordered itemslists" style="width: auto; min-width:880px;" id="tbl_edit">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td width="100px"><input type="text" name="item_qty[]" id="item_qty" class="item_qty form-control aaa" value="2"></td>
                <td width="520px"><input type="text" name="item_name[]" id="item_name" class="form-control" value="2"></td>
                <td width="180px">
                    <select name="item_dvsn[]" class="form-control">
                        <option value="Genel Yönetim">Genel Yönetim</option> 
                        <option value="Satış">Satış</option>
                        <option value="Pazarlama">Pazarlama</option>                             
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td width="80px">
                    <select name="item_fixture[]" class="form-control">
                        <option class="limit" value="Evet" selected="">Evet</option>
                        <option class="limit" value="Hayır">Hayır</option>                                  
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td width="130px"><input type="text" name="item_unitp[]" id="item_unitp" class="item_unitp form-control sss" style="text-align:right;" value="3"></td>
                <td width="80px"><input type="text" name="item_tax[]" id="item_tax" class="item_tax form-control ddd" style="text-align:center;" value="0"></td>
                <td width="130px"><input type="text" name="item_totalp[]" id="item_totalp" class="item_totalp form-control fff" style="text-align:right;" value="6,00"></td>
                                        
                <td class="hide"><input type="text" name="item_id[]" class="borderless editbg left" style="display:none;" value="10"></td>
                <td><button type="button" id="remove_10" name="remove" data-row="1" value="10" class="remove buttonremoveline btn-danger btn-xs">-</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="100px"><input type="text" name="item_qty[]" id="item_qty" class="item_qty form-control aaa" value="2"></td>
                <td width="520px"><input type="text" name="item_name[]" id="item_name" class="form-control" value="2"></td>
                <td width="180px">
                    <select name="item_dvsn[]" class="form-control">
                        <option value="Satış">Satış</option>
                        <option value="Pazarlama">Pazarlama</option>                                     
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td width="80px">
                    <select name="item_fixture[]" class="form-control">
                        <option class="limit" value="Evet" selected="">Evet</option>
                        <option class="limit" value="Hayır">Hayır</option>                              
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td width="130px"><input type="text" name="item_unitp[]" id="item_unitp" class="item_unitp form-control sss" style="text-align:right;" value="2"></td>
                <td width="80px"><input type="text" name="item_tax[]" id="item_tax" class="item_tax form-control ddd" style="text-align:center;" value="0"></td>
                <td width="130px"><input type="text" name="item_totalp[]" id="item_totalp" class="item_totalp form-control fff" style="text-align:right;" value="4,00"></td>                                
                <td class="hide"><input type="text" name="item_id[]" class="borderless editbg left" style="display:none;" value="89"></td>
                <td><button type="button" id="remove_89" name="remove" data-row="2" value="89" class="remove buttonremoveline btn-danger btn-xs">-</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="100px"><input type="text" name="item_qty[]" id="item_qty" class="item_qty form-control aaa" value=""></td>
                <td width="520px"><input type="text" name="item_name[]" id="item_name" class="form-control" value=""></td>
                <td width="180px">
                    <select name="item_dvsn[]" class="form-control">
                        <option value="Satış">Satış</option>
                        <option value="Pazarlama">Pazarlama</option>                                     
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td width="80px">
                    <select name="item_fixture[]" class="form-control">
                        <option class="limit" value="Evet">Evet</option>
                        <option class="limit" value="Hayır">Hayır</option>                              
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td width="130px"><input type="text" name="item_unitp[]" id="item_unitp" class="item_unitp form-control sss" style="text-align:right;" value=""></td>
                <td width="80px"><input type="text" name="item_tax[]" id="item_tax" class="item_tax form-control ddd" style="text-align:center;" value="0"></td>
                <td width="130px"><input type="text" name="item_totalp[]" id="item_totalp" class="item_totalp form-control fff" style="text-align:right;" value=""></td>
                                        
                <td class="hide"><input type="text" name="item_id[]" class="borderless editbg left" style="display:none;" value="109"></td>
                <td><button type="button" id="remove_109" name="remove" data-row="3" value="109" class="remove buttonremoveline btn-danger btn-xs">-</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Why are there two click handlers for `.remove` ?

Comment: Please add some of the rendered HTML so that we might understand the layout/structure of the page

Comment: @76484 actually it was idea of ChatGPT :) when it is removed then remove button does not function.

Comment: I'm not really sure what your issue is. It sounds like you need something very simple, like: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/p73j5f2a/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are *already* using [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) with your `$(document).on("click", ".remove", function() {})` handler, so I'm not really sure what your issue is. I am guessing you need just simplify your logic. I think the following should be fine:

```
$(document).on("click", ".remove", function() {
  const $button = $(this);
  const buttonId = $button.attr('id');
  const rowId = buttonId.split('_')[1];

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/cbdelrow.php',
    data: {
      btn_val: rowId
    },
    success: function(response) {
      // remove the row of the clicked button
      $button.closest('tr').remove();
      update_amounts();

      const $remove = $('.remove');
      
      // if there is only 1 .remove button remaining, hide it
      if ($remove.length === 1) {
        $remove.hide();
      }
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      alert('Error while delete.');
    }
  });
});
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/p73j5f2a/) is an example fiddle.

Comment: You are correct, I should construct without distruction. Thank you for your guidance.